# Method to count edges from root to furthest node in tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, edges

I am trying to write a method that will calculate the largest amount of edges taken to get from the root to the furthest node.

```
public static int depth(Tree t) {
    if(t == null) return 0;
    else return 1 + Math.max(depth(t.left), depth(t.right));
}
```

[image: Tree]

The method should show an answer of 3 for this tree, however it is currently giving a result of 4 as it is counting the nodes rather than the edges, therefore counting the initial root. How would I go about changing this to give the correct result?

Comment: If you already have an algorithm to calculate a path length in term of nodes then the same path length in term of edges will be always 1 unit less.

Comment: Your algorithm counts the leaf nodes `93` and `41` as depth 4, with your root node as depth 1.

Comment: Yes I realise this, I just can't figure out how to return the value -1 in the method as it is recursive, without hacking it in when the method is called which is a little untidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your recursive method in an  outer method that tests for a `null` tree and subtracts one from the result:

```
public static int depth(Tree t) {
  return (t == null) ? 0 : calculateDepth(t) - 1;
}

private static int calculateDepth(Tree t) {
  if (t == null)
    return 0;
  else
    return 1 + Math.max(calculateDepth(t.left), calculateDepth(t.right));
}
```

Comment: I had considered this, but I need to return 0 when the node is null

Comment: I would make the check `if (t == null || t.left == null && t.right == null) { return 0; }` then. One big problem is that you consider the empty tree to be the same depth as a tree with 1 node.

Comment: @user3371750 Actually, the comment solution from Phylogenesis exhibits the same behaviour as mine without the need for a wrapper. Not sure why I didn't read that comment properly first time.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Post your solution - it's better.

Comment: @Duncan I don't think it is. I think the whole premise of the depth of the tree in the question being 3 is inaccurate. Why should the `null` tree and a tree consisting of a single node be considered to have equal depth? It makes no sense.